# switching between local planner in ROS2

Tags: ros2, path-planning, nav2, dwa-local-planner, ros-galactic

I am wondering will if be possible in ROS2 to have 2 different local planners and be able to switch between them.

For example, I want to use both pure-pursuit planner and DWA planner.
Let's say that I have a camera that can identify whether if there is any obstacle in front of me. Under normal operation, when there is not obstacle, I want the ros2 planner to use pure-pursuit planner. However, in case of obstacles present, I want the ros2 local planner to switch to using DWA planner instead.I want the ros2 local planner to switch to using DWA planner instead.

Thus, I wonder what I will need to change in my configuration to reflect this feature?

Thanks all in advance!